# datetime.timestamp() during the DST start and end day

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am facing some issues due to the DST conversion. I have the following code.

```
from datetime import datetime
date1=datetime.strptime('03/11/2018 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' )
date1_insecs=date1.timestamp()
elapsed_seconds= 186*60  #(3 hours and 6 minutes)
date2=datetime.fromtimestamp(date1_insecs+elapsed_seconds)
print(date2)
```

The output is:

> 2018-03-11 04:06:00

I expect 'date2' to be '2018-03-11 03:06:00', but I get 'date2' as '2018-03-11 04:06:00'. Is there some way to get date2 as '2018-03-11 03:06:00'. Similar remedy for the DST ending day.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `2018-03-11 02:06:00` isn't a time that exists in timezones with daylight savings kicking in on that day. If you want a time that ignores daylight savings, you may need to specify a timezone like UTC where it isn't used.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question as 02:06 won't exists when DST starts.

Comment: @Blckknght Can I specify the timezone to be UTC without converting the time? When I do `date1=date1.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` and `print (datetime.fromtimestamp(date1.timestamp()))` I get a different time than what `date1` was.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime('03/11/2018 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' )
# 2018-03-11 00:00:00

date1_insecs = date1.timestamp()
elapsed_seconds = 186*60  #(3 hours and 6 minutes)

date2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(date1_insecs + elapsed_seconds)
# 2018-03-11 03:06:00
```